# Sending 2 parameters back to Main function

Tags: c#, parameters, .net-2.0

I got a function which wants to send 2 `INT` parameters back to where it has been called, but not sure what would be the best option, a `Dictionary` ? or a `List` or an `Array`

**EDITED**

**I am using .Net framework 2**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean return 2 values to the caller. If so:

- return a `Tuple<T1, T2>`
- return your own custom type which stores the desired values, like `MyOperationResult`
- use `out` parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx
- return a collection

It depends on what is easiest for the caller to understand, i.e. what best demonstrates your intention?

Returning a variable-size collection may not be intuitive if the result will **always** have two values. My preference is either a Tuple or a custom type. A Tuple has the advantage of being an existing type, but the disadvantage that it's not clear what its members mean; they are just called "Item1", "Item2", and so on.

The `out` keyword is nice for operations which may not succeed and always return a bool, like `public bool int.TryParse( string value, out int parsedValue )`. Here the intent is clear.

Comment: use out parameters ? never heard of it before

Comment: Added a link regarding the `out` keyword.

Comment: Custom type with two int values would be my choice then...but nothing wrong with out parameters (which are supported in 2.0).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738042/error-the-out-parameter-must-be-assigned-before-control-leaves-the-current-met

Answer (score 2):

try with this code

```
type1 param1;
type2 param2;
void Send(out type1 param1, out type2 param2)

or

type1 param1 = ..;//You must initialize with ref
type2 param2 = ..;
void Send(ref type1 param1, ref type2 param2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with out parameter [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you're only ever using two ints, then I'd use a 2-tuple, a `Tuple<int, int>`.

You can initialise it with its two values in the constructor:

```
return new Tuple<int,int>(val1, val2);
```

Alternatively for a variable number of outputs, a `List<int>` (or perhaps just an `IEnumerable<int>` depending on the intended use).

Answer (score 2):

i think i need to return it by refference, like so....

```
private void ReturnByRef(ref int i1, ref int i2) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends, you'd have multiple ways to do that.
If it's just two parameters you want to pass back, then you could just use "out" parameters:

```
class A
{
  private static void foo(int param, out int res1, out int res2)
  {
    res1 = 1*param;
    res2 = 2*param;
  }

  public static void main(string[] args)
  {
    int res1, res2;
    foo(1, out res1, out res2);
    // Do something with your results ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

out parameter works best

```
static void Main()
{
   int a;
   int b;
   someFunction(out a,out b); //the int values will be returned in a and b
   Console.WriteLine(a);
   Console.WriteLine(b);
}
public static void someFunction(out int x,out int y)
{
   x=10;
   y=20;
 }
```

your output wil be

```
10
20
```