# Error : The Out Parameter must be assigned before control leaves the current method

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, .net-2.0

While sending back parameters getting this error

> Error : The Out Parameter must be assigned before control leaves the
>   current method

Code is

```
 public void GetPapers(string web, out int Id1, out int Id2)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString());
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPapers", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@URL", String(web)));

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            Id1 = (int)rdr["ID1"];
            Id2 = (int)rdr["ID2"];
        }

        rdr.Close();
    }
```

calling it as

```
GetPapers(web, out Id1, out Id2);
```

Related to this question

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737497/sending-2-parameters-back-to-main-function/11737538#comment15577485_11737538)

Comment: Out parameters must be assigned along all paths before control leaves the method. Since you have an if statement, they may not get assigned.

Comment: What do you want the values to be if `rdr.Read()` returns false?

Comment: @JonSkeet code only works when there is something in DB, its like a event receiver

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg: So perhaps you ought to be throwing an exception when there isn't anything in the database?

Comment: @JonSkeet yup, I will do the validations later on then :)

Comment: @JonSkeet What is the wisdom behind this requirement? if I initialize Count=0 and then call a function foo(..., out Count); that only should increment Count if it found matches, why should the function update Count otherwise?  Thank you.

Comment: @Meryan: Because that's what `out` means... if it's intended to *increment* `count` then it should use `ref` instead of `out`.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you! I was not aware ref existed :), viva Pascal

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are assigning `Id1` and `Id2` inside an if statement and compiler can't determine if it will be assigned a value at run time, thus the error.

You could assign them some default value before the if statement. Something like.

```
Id1 = 0;
Id2 = 0;

if (rdr.Read())
{
    Id1 = (int)rdr["ID1"];
    Id2 = (int)rdr["ID2"];
}
```

or specify some default values in `else` part of your condition.

An `out` type parameter must be assigned some value, before the control leaves the functions. In your case, compiler can't determine whether your variables will be assigned or not, because it  is being assigned inside an `if` statement.

See: [5.3 Definite assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172(v=vs.71).aspx)

> At a given location in the executable code of a function member, a
>   variable is said to be definitely assigned **if the compiler can
>   prove, by static flow analysis,** that the variable has been
>   automatically initialized or has been the target of at least one
>   assignment.

Comment: Wow, this seems super broken, why would they make this design choice?

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialise those variables ;

it must hold some value before returned from the Getpapers() method